# Does Java syntax for iteration across arrays allocate memory?

Tags: java

I am programming for a memory-constrained device. Hence, I want to avoid allocating any memory.

Obviously, iterating across sets, lists, etc will allocate an iterator and thus allocate memory. So this should be avoided.

Does the native java syntax for iterating across arrays allocate memory?

```
Object[] array = getArray()
for(Object elem: array){
  //do something
}
```

(I suppose I could always use the old-fashioned for loop with an index variable.)

Comment: I wasn't aware that one could disable the JVM garbage-collector.  How does **anything** work in that scenario?

Comment: ... and more importantly, can that be called Java?

Comment: You're right, the GC is not completely disabled - we just want to avoid having it run, so I prefer to view it as such.

Comment: Refer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369730/java-for-loop-differences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. In all compilers that I have checked this is implemented by a `for` loop (0..array.lengh-1).

Note that Java arrays do not implement `Iterable`. This can be seen, for instance, by the following code:

```
Object[] arr = new String[100];
Iterable<?> iter = arr;  // Error: 'Type mismatch: 
                         //         cannot convert from Object[] to Iterable<?>'
```

**[UPDATE]**

And here is the definite source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

A for loop such as

> ```
> for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
> ```

has the following meaning when Expression is an array of type T[]:

> ```
> T[] a = Expression;
> for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>        VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = a[i];
>        Statement
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't allocate new memory. The following foreach loop:

```
for (type var : array) {
    body-of-loop
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    type var = array[i];
    body-of-loop
}
```

As you can see, no additional memory allocation is being made.

Comment: To  be specific it takes some stak space for type var = array[i] ;)

Comment: Well, `int i` and `type var` _do_ allocate a bit of stack memory (and a constant value), but no additional _heap_ memory is allocated.